# Один метод или несколько?

Tags: база-данных, оптимизация

Представте такую ситуацию. Имеется база данных и некоторое приложение (веб или десктоп) которое получает информацию из этой базы. Выглядит примерно так

[image]

То есть какаято таблица которая генерируется из базы данных по нескольким условиям. У меня появился такой вопрос. Как правильно получать данные из базы с помощью модели?  Нужно ли писать  для этого один большой метод с кучей параметров некоторые из которых часто будут параметрами по умолчанию  или надо писать много-много методов на каждый случай и таким образом дублировать одну и ту же логику получения данных в разных методах?

То есть в первом случае у меня получается чтото такое

```
public IEnuerable<Someclass> GetData(int firstFilter, string secondFilter, 
                                     int   thirdFilter = -1, 
                                     DateTime fourthFilter = default(DateTime)
                                     ....
                                     T nthFilter = defaualt(T)) 
{
      string sql = @"select * 
                     from Table 
                     where  firstCol = @first and @secondCol = @second";
     if(thirdFilter != -1)
         sql += " AND thirdCol = @third ";

     if(fourthFilter != default(DateTime))
         sql += " AND forthCol = @fourth";

     //   и так далее для всех параметров

     // логика по получению данных
     ......
     return someData;
}
```

этот вариант плох черезчур раздутым методом и кучей условий и параметров по умолчанию

во втором варианте получаю такое

```
public IEnuerable<Someclass> GetDataFirst(int filter)
{ 
    string sql = @"select * 
                   from Table 
                   where  firstCol = @filter";

     // логика по получению данных
     ......
     return someData;
}

public IEnuerable<Someclass> GetDataSecond(int filter)
{ 
    string sql = @"select * 
                   from Table 
                   where  secondCol = @filter";

     // логика по получению данных
     ......
     return someData;
}

/// и еще куча похожих методов
```

В общем я теряюсь в догадках как лучше организовать получение данных без дублирования кода и без раздувания размеров этих методов. Заранее спасибо за помощь

Comment: Первый вариант. Второй вариант ни в какие ворота не лезет ввиду того, что вместо одного запроса к БД будет четыре запроса, что существенно медленнее.

Comment: я не имею в виду что все 4 запроса надо делать одновременно. Каждый метод нужен для определенной ситуации. Например один для того чтобы получить пользователей по определенной фамилии, другой чтобы по возрасту и так далее

Comment: используйте тот метод, который создает наименьшую нагрузку на СУБД, а так же код, который легко читаемый и понимаемый. 
Никто же не мешает использовать перегруженые методы...

Comment: так ведь все равно же нужно отбирать данные по каким то параметрам даже если использовать хранимые процедуры или Linq. А параметров может быть много

Comment: В чем проблема передать много параметров?

Comment: Мне без разницы через что получать данные - через linq, ado или что то еще. Мне важно то как организовать методы для получения данных по множеству параметров некоторые из которых могут присутствовать или отсутствовать в конкретном запросе

Comment: При использовании хранимых процедур или LINQ просто отпадает необходимость в приведенных выше функциях.

Comment: Почему? Допустим  мне надо получить из таблицы пользователей всех пользователей мужского в возрасте от 20 до 40 лет с фамилиями начинающимися с буквы В. Как мне это сделать хранимой процедурой без этих функций? Я же где то должен задавать эти условия. Кроме того не обязательно код должен быть на C# поэтому linq не очень универсальное решение

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал вообще отказаться от перечисленных подходов. По сути Вы сейчас делаете велосипед - свой конструктор запросов.
Вариантов готовых решений есть великое множество. Можно создавать хранимые процедуры в СУБД и вызывать непосредственно их. Можно использовать LINQ. Можно CommandBuilder задействовать. Возможности ADO.NET и современных СУБД позволяют это.

Для простоты объяснения акцентируем внимание на каком-то одном из предложенных мною вариантов. На хранимых процедурах. После проектирования приложения, реализации БД и менеджера данных у Вас должен быть более-менее фиксированный набор хранимых процедур.

Допустим, Вам нужно удалить фотографию из галереи. Для этого у Вас создана отдельная хранимая процедура, что принимает параметр - уникальный идентификатор фото. Вы ее вызываете, она срабатывает, все довольны. Еще у Вас есть необходимость удалить все фотографии конкретного пользователя. Для этого Вы не используете вышеописанную хранимую процедуру, а создаете новую, которая принимает параметром уникальный ИД пользователя.

Comment: > Почему? Допустим мне надо получить из
> таблицы пользователей всех
> пользователей мужского в возрасте от
> 20 до 40 лет с фамилиями начинающимися
> с буквы В. Как мне это сделать
> хранимой процедурой без этих функций?
> Я же где то должен задавать эти
> условия. Кроме того не обязательно код
> должен быть на C# поэтому linq не
> очень универсальное решение

Создать stored procedure с выборкой по возрасту и фамилии. Вызывать хранимую процедуру там, где нужны данные, что она возвращает.

LINQ можно использовать в любом .NET ЯП.

Comment: 1) речь вообще о любых языках - хоть c# хоть php хоть java
2) как без указания параметров получить данные об этих пользователях от 20 до 40 лет мужского пола с фамилией на букву В? Как?

Comment: > как без указания параметров получить данные об этих пользователях > от 20 до 40 лет мужского пола с фамилией на букву В? Как?

Почему без указания параметров? В ответе же описан пример. Параметры передаются  хранимой процедуре. Зачем создавать функции? Вызывали конкретную stored procedue в нужно месте с нужными параметрами, забрали результат, вывели его, PROFIT!

> речь вообще о любых языках - хоть c# хоть php хоть java

Вы спрашиваете как правильно получать данные из базы с помощью модели. Так вот, для .NET своя модель и свои методы, в JAVA все немного по-другому, PHP то уже другая песня.

Comment: У разных технологий и/или ЯП разные коннекторы к СУБД. Свои драйвера для работы с СУБД. Работа с ними специфична. Нету универсального решения. Есть только попытки реализации последнего: PDO, ADO.NET...

Comment: блин ну я же не говорю про конкретные технологии! Поймите же наконец - речь о том что надо получать данные по многочисленным параметрам многие из которых могут либо отсутствовать либо присутствовать. я уже приводил пример - в одном запросе мне нужно получить пользователей-мужчин от 20 до 40 лет с фамилией на букву В. В другом например всех пользователей не старше 30 лет живущих в Москве, и так далее.Мне не нужны конкретные технологии доступа к данным в конкретных языках. Мне нужно элегантное решение которое позволит выбирать данные по многочисленным вариативным параметрам запроса.

Comment: Забавно, когда же наши параллели пересекутся наконец =)

Я понял Вас, надеюсь, еще когда прочитал вопрос. Беда в том, что вышеуказанное "элегантное решение", которое Вы ищите, в каждой технологии свое.

Да, Вы можете наклепать функций с параметрами по-умолчанию или перезагруженных функций. Да, они будут вызывать SQL. Да, это будет что-то типа конструктора запросов. Но это не элегантное решение. Элегантное решение это PDO в PHP, это LINQ в .NET и т.п.

Comment: Хорошо. возьмем c#. Есть таблица пользователей в ней хранится информация по ним. Много информации. Например такие поля - фамилия, имя, отчество, пол, дата рождения, рост, вес, страна, город, профессия и тд. Нужна возможность выбирать пользователей по некоторым критериям - любым из вышеуказанных. По возрасту и полу, по городу, стране и профессии, по первой букве имени. По чему угодно в любых сочетаниях. Как это реализовать скажем с помощью c#? Как будет выглядеть код для выборки этих значений? Можете показать кодом хотя бы в общих чертах?